# Digitally signing a PDF, using PHP, Zend, and openssl

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, openssl, sign

I'm trying to build a simple PDF document signing routine, using PHP, openssl, and the Zend framework (for pdf redering/handling).

I've found [this](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10950), but it simply won't work, Zend is not able to open any pdf's, not even Zend's own test pdf and Zend will not report why, only that it 'cannot'.

I'm pretty sure I would be able to create the keys/certs effectively as that is well documented, but is there a solid approach to attaching the generated certificate to the PDF as the above Zend extension suggests it once did?

```
function DigiSignPDF ($pdf_sign_request) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $new_pdf = stripslashes($pdf_sign_request['raw_pdf']);
    } else {
        $new_pdf = $pdf_sign_request['raw_pdf'];
    }
    $test_pdf = stripslashes(file_get_contents('path/Some.pdf'));
    $test_pdf2 = ('path/Some.pdf');
    $pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($new_pdf2);
    //below is the signing code, from another library, it works as long as Zend_Pdf works
    $certificate = file_get_contents('path/certificate.p12');
    $certificatePassword = 'test123';

    if (empty($certificate)) {
        throw new Zend_Pdf_Exception('Cannot retrieve/generate the certificate.');
    }
    $pdf->attachDigitalCertificate($certificate,$certificatePassword);
    $eSig_pdf = $pdf->render();
    file_put_contents('path/signed_pdf.pdf', $eSig_pdf);
}
```

Edit, adding code: The above only works if I use 'test_pdf2' as the input for Zend_Pdf. It recognizes the cert as binary with no problems, but I need to be able to pass the PDF without ever writing it to disk.

Comment: Ok, so I may have gotten closer. What's happening is that PHP insists on inserting slashes, newline, carriage return characters into the file, no matter if I upload it, or read it from a local disk using file_get_contents. I am aware of and have tried stripslashes, declaring magic_quotes off, etc. I can only get it to work if I have Zend_Pdf read the file directly, which won't work for me because we will not be writing any of these files to a disk, ever. Is there anyway to convince PHP that it should not be tampering with the data it's asked to handle?

Comment: Can we see your code that you're using to handle the PDF? Edit it into your question.

Comment: Solved this one, because I was passing the content to Zend_Pdf as a string, i should have been using Zend_Pdf::parse($new_pdf);, as it very likely says in the manual. (oops)

Comment: Further; I solved pretty much ALL of my problems with digitally signing PDFs of various versions and form constituents by moving to TCPDF, as several of the articles here suggest. A similar caveat was met with TCPDF though, when using strings, ensure that you are using TCPDF's 'writeHTMLCell' instead of 'writeHTML'. And watch for PHPs 'magic_quotes', errant whitespace, encoding, and goblins.

Comment: ^ I suggest you add your solution as an answer (as standard practice here) and delete your solution comments above.

Comment: How to positioning(x and y position) the signature by using this method?

Answer (score 11):

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) supports [signing](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps) of pdf files. Maybe you find something useful in the source code.

Comment: I did come across that library, unfortunately we will not be able to use any outside code (other than the existing zend framework). Good suggestion though.

Comment: @user1437888 - can you edit your question to specify that condition? If you can give some background as to why that's the case, so much the better - it may help guide answers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my solution as answer, per halfer's advice:  Solved this one, because I was passing the content to Zend_Pdf as a string, i should have been using Zend_Pdf::parse($new_pdf);, as it very likely says in the manual. (oops)

Further; I solved pretty much ALL of my problems with digitally signing PDFs of various versions and form constituents by moving to TCPDF, as several of the articles here suggest. A similar caveat was met with TCPDF though, when using strings, ensure that you are using TCPDF's 'writeHTMLCell' instead of 'writeHTML'. And watch for PHPs 'magic_quotes', errant whitespace, encoding, and goblins.

Comment: This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8537628/loic-angora) asks: *can i have the function "attachDigitalCertificate()". I try to sign digitally PDF with zendpdf and i've some issues.*